# Adding letters in hyphenation of Swedish words

Tags: languages, hyphenation

Swedish writing conventions states that in compound words, when three successive identical consonants occur, one of them should be omitted. An example of this is *glass* (ice cream) and *strut* (cone), which form the compound word *glasstrut* (ice cream cone), not *glassstrut*.

Another example is *ägg* and *gula*, which forms *äggula* (egg yolk), not *ägggula*.

It might seem like a strange rule, and sometimes it creates strange results. As an example, it is impossible to distinguish between the written words *glass-strut* (ice cream cone) *glass-trut* (a gull made of ice cream) and *glas-strut* (a cone made of glass), but most words don't have this ambiguity (*äggula* can't mean anything else besides egg yolk regardless how it's pronounced).

However, if a hyphenation occur between the two consonants, the third one should be added.
This means that *äggula* should be hyphenated as *ägg-gula*. Other examples would be *till-låta*, *till-lämpa*, *topp-position*.

Is it possible to achive this kind of hyphenation with Latex? Ideally, I am searching for a solution both for the whole document (like \hyphenation works, for i.e. *äggula*) and in the text, for cases like *glasstrut* which could be hyphenated differently depending on the meaning (*glass-strut*, *glass-trut*).

Testing shows that none of the above words gets correct hyphenation (using Polyglossia and Xelatex). If I add an entry manually with \hyphenation, I get the hyphenation at the correct place, but I don't know how I could add the "missing" letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\begin{document}
\hyphenation{glass-trut}
Oh Norrmalmsregleringen, ho samt Västerbron och Tranebergsbron. glasstrut krigsåren var Larsson även en ledande nordisk 
\end{document}
```

(Hyphenation should occur in the word "glasstrut", the other words are just there for filling)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  nice examples.  there's a command `\discretionary` that can be used to do what you want, but i don't use it often enough to write an answer off the top of my head; i'll have to look it up.  (unless someone else gets there first.)

Comment: a slightly different approach, also using `\discretionary` with examples from the texbook, is posted with this question: [When hyphenation of a word includes an additional letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235022/579)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not possible with XeTeX, but something can be done with LuaTeX.

When (Xe)TeX decides for a possible hyphenation point it basically adds `\discretionary{-}{}{}`, while in the case of "äggula" you want

```
ägg\discretionary{-}{g}{}ula
```

and this is usually solved by something like

```
\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{\nobreak\hskip0pt\relax}
\newcommand{\ggg}{gg\discretionary{-}{\allowhyphens g}{}}
```

and inputting the word as

```
ä\ggg ula
```

(`\allowhyphens` allows TeX to break also the remainder of the composite word).

Cases like "glasstrut" where semantics is involved are best solved by not allowing hyphenation, resorting to manual insertion of `\discretionary` (maybe hidden in a macro) in cases splitting the word becomes necessary. See exercise 14.8 in the TeXbook (page 96).

---

With LuaTeX the situation is *very* different; you can specify

```
\hyphenation{ägg{-}{g}{}ula}
```

(there's no point in adding a new hyphenation point "äggu-la", I believe). Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\hyphenation{ägg{-}{g}{}ula}
\begin{document}

äggula

\parbox[t]{1pt}{äggula}
\end{document}
```

The three pairs of braces specify what's in the "pre-break", "post-break" and "no-break" parts just like the arguments to `\discretionary`.

[image]

Comment: where there's more than one of the possible different-but-lookalike words in a document, one could use different macros to identify them, with the `\discretionary` value built in.  (this happens in english too, though almost never with different spelling.  for example, `\newcommand{\recordnoun}{rec\discretionary{-}{}{}ord` vs. `\newcommand{\recordverb}{re\discretionary{-}{}{}cord`.)  @egreg -- do you really want `\allowbreaks` there?  that would presumably allow a break after a *third* `g`.  the answer to exercise `4.8 (p.314) doesn't have one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I was thinking to `\allowhyphens`.

Comment: Good answer, solves my problem. The Luatex solution was exactly what I was looking for, looks like I might switch to Luatex in the near future.

Answer (score 5):

There is in fact a functionality for these situations built into the babel-package (however not in polyglossia what I have seen). Specifically, the command is

"ff

for ff to be hyphenated as ff-f. Used for compound words, such as stra"ffånge, which should be hyphenated as straff-fånge. This is also implemented for b, d, f, g, l, m, n, p, r, s, and t.

Here I have cited the documentation page found as /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.pdf in my distro (TeXlive/Debian).