# When hyphenation of a word includes an additional letter

Tags: hyphenation

In some languages a word on the form *abcxxdef* (note that there is only two occurrences of the letter *x*) is the compound of the two words *abcxx* and *xdef*. Sometimes the hyphenation rule is to break the word into its two parts: *abcxx*-*xdef*. Note that the letter *x* now occurs three times. How can I, for a specific word, tell LaTeX to hyphenate this way?

Comment: Just as usual. Either globally as `\hyphenation{abcxx-xdef}`, or case-wise when writing the word in the text `abcxx\-xdef`.

Comment: No, `abcxx\-xdef` renders to *abcxxxdef* (three *x*s) if not hyphenated. The word is not spelt with three *x*s if not hyphenated. I've updated the question to emphasize this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

to accomplish such complex hyphenation requires use of the `\discretionary{}{}{}`
(primitive) facility of tex.

this answer quoted from the *TeXbook* (exercise 14.8, which hides behind a
"dangerous bend").

> Before 1998, some German words changed their spelling when split
>   between lines. For example, "backen" became "bak-ken" and "Bettuch"
>   sometimes became "Bett-tuch". How can you instruct TeX to produce such
>   effects?

answer:

> `ba\ck/en` and `Be\ttt/uch`, where the macros `\ck/` and `\ttt/` are
>   defined by
>
> ```
> \def\ck/{\discretionary{k-}{k}{ck}}
> \def\ttt/{tt\discretionary{-}{t}{}}
> ```
>
> The English word "eighteen" might deserve similar treatment. TeX's
>   hyphenation algorithm will not make such spelling changes
>   automatically.

Comment: Brilliant! The "Bettuch" example applies to many Scandinavian words as well.

Comment: @DustByte: "applies to many Scandinavian words" ... I am from Denmark, and I have never heard of this tripling of consonant before. Is there a wikipedia site, or other reference describing this phenomenon?

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87210/adding-letters-in-hyphenation-of-swedish-words) are some examples from a trusted site.

Comment: @Jon: thanks for the link above. Had missed it. Most likely it applies not only to Swedish. I am not a Norwegian speaker, but the Norwegian word "musikkurs" (music course) comes from "musikk" + "kurs", and will probably be hyphenated "musikk-kurs" is there a line break. That is why I wrote "Scandinavian words".